# Which DC power jack to use with AC-AC adapter

Tags: power-supply

I bought an AC-AC adapter for a project (takes 120 VAC mains and produces 12 VAC/3.5 A). It has a regular DC power jack (2.5mm I.D., 5.5mm O.D.) and I want to purchase a DC power jack to connect to it.

However, all DC power jacks I could find are rated for a specific DC voltage and current.

Are there any AC-rated DC power jacks on the market, or must I use a DC-rated one? Are there any special considerations I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DC barrel jack for AC. In fact, the jack that can handle 12VDC @3.5A would be more than sufficient for 12VAC, since AC RMS power will be less than corresponding DC power (that's assuming your AC voltage spec is peak amplitude)

See for example this [digikey search](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/barrel-power-connectors/435?k=&pkeyword=&pv80=9&FV=fff40016%2Cfff80518%2C38000a%2C38007f%2C3800a7%2C3806b8%2C380129%2C380187%2C38018f%2C380050%2C740001%2C440002d%2C4400031%2C1e88001d%2C1e88001f%2C1f140000%2Cmu10A%7C2088%2Cmu4A%7C2088%2Cmu5A%7C2088%2Cmu6A%7C2088%2Cmu8A%7C2088%2Cffe001b3&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25)